# How to append array and insert into single field in oracle

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I am not sure whether the title is correct or not

I have created a following table

```
create table healthcheck
(
fordate date default sysdate,
tablespace_status varchar2(100),
comments varchar2(200)
);
```

now in a PL/SQL code I use the following statement

```
select tablespace_name, used_percent 
from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics 
where used_percent > 70;
```

For ex, the output of the above query is:

```
USERS  75
TEMP   80
```

Now i want this output to be stored in the column `tablespace_status` as 'USERS:75%,TEMP:80%' in one single field.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below snipet helps. 
Note : WMSYS.WM_CONCAT is undocumented function so if object present in you database it will definetely worK. Alternative is LISTAGG.

```
Approach 1 :LISTAGG

    CREATE TABLE healthcheck
  (
    fordate           DATE DEFAULT sysdate,
    tablespace_status VARCHAR2(100),
    COMMENTS          VARCHAR2(200)
  );



    INSERT INTO HEALTHCHECK
SELECT sysdate,
  LISTAGG(tablespace_name
  ||':'
  ||ROUND(USED_PERCENT)
  ||':'
  ||Dbname, ', ') within GROUP (
ORDER BY tablespace_name DESC) status,
  NULL
FROM
  (SELECT tablespace_name,
    USED_PERCENT ,
    (SELECT global_name FROM global_name@dblink1
    ) Dbname
  FROM DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS@dblink1
  WHERE USED_PERCENT > 70
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tablespace_name ,
    USED_PERCENT ,
    (SELECT global_name FROM global_name@dblink2
    ) Dbname
  FROM DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS@dblink2
  WHERE USED_PERCENT > 70
    --union all for all 5 dblinks
  )a ;
```

1 rows inserted.

```
Approach 2 : WMSYS.WM_CONCAT

    INSERT INTO HEALTHCHECK
    SELECT sysdate,
      WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(a.fld),
      NULL
    FROM
      (SELECT tablespace_name
        ||':'
        ||round(used_percent)||':'||ORA_DATABASE_NAME fld
      FROM DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS
      WHERE used_percent > 70
      )A;
```

1 rows inserted.

Comment: Is this solution helped you? If yes can u please accept the answer?

Comment: For Approach 1, the error is coming as too many values and for approach 2, the error is coming as missing right parenthesis. Could you please help?

Comment: Also if you can suggest which approach is best for performance tuning, that would be great.

Comment: Approach 1 will be good for tuning purpose. Also the query is working fine. Could you please check how you are running the query. Also could you please check which version of oracle you are running?

Comment: Approach 1 is working but the requirement is to fetch the tablespace from 5 different database and wherever the tablespace is >70%, i need to insert that in one single field i.e. tablespace_status column.
Also if you can help me to insert it like 'tablespacename:tablespacepercent:dbname', that would be really great!!

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts for your valuable comment.

Comment: Also for approach 1, the mistake was from my side. So i fixed it.

Comment: Edited the answer to include Database name. Please check. Also plz update the question as per the request so that it can be useful to others.

Comment: I have also created database link to connect to different database. So i just need to mention @dblink name after table name HEALTHCHECK.

Comment: yes it will work like this. Also please accept the answer if it helped yo

Comment: i will definitely accept but can you please suggest on how to insert the same for 5 different database in single field. Please read my above comments.

Comment: Make union for all the queries for different DBLINKS and then apply listagg on top of it.

Comment: Updated the answer for Approach 1. If you have any further updates in question.please go with a new question. Also please accept the answer.

Comment: I am checking on this. We are almost done but the database name is not coming as per expectation. It's showing the same db name from where i am running the query whereas the tablespace name and its percent is getting fetched properly. I don't have any additional question. This is it.

Comment: select * from global_name@dblink; -- compitible with dblink.

select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual@dblink; -- not compitible with dblink.

select ora_database_name from dual@dblink; --not compitible with dblink.

Comment: I tried to replace ora_Database_Name with global_name but its showing as invalid identifier.

Comment: I have edited the answer to go with global_name with dblink Hope this meets your rquirement. I have not ran this qiery as i dont have workspace with me. Let m eknow